# Python: Printing the letter "N" using "X" and "O"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have just started to learn how to use python. Here is my code:

```
def print_N_inside_rectangle(n, m) : 
      
    for i in range(1, n+1) : 
        for j in range(1, m+1) : 
            if (i == 0 or
                j == 1 or j == m) : 
                print("x", end="")
            else : 
                print("o", end="")             
          
        print() 

rows = int(input("Enter row:"))
columns = int(input("Enter column:"))
print_N_inside_rectangle(rows, columns)
```

I input row=7 column=7 and here is the result

```
XOOOOOX
XOOOOOX
XOOOOOX
XOOOOOX
XOOOOOX
XOOOOOX
XOOOOOX
```

The result that I want should look like this:

```
XOOOOOX
XXOOOOX
XOXOOOX
XOOXOOX
XOOOXOX
XOOOOXX
XOOOOOX
```

Can anyone help me edit my code ,so the result print the big capital "N" using "X".

Comment: Where specifically are you stuck? I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: What does a capital N look like?

Comment: look at second result, a letter "X" is plotting a capital "N"

Comment: Think about what you want the code to do in addition to what it does now, for example: "I want to put an X on row 1, column 1, and then X on row 2, column 2 and then...etc". This will give you a hint to what you need to add to the inner loop for the N to print.

Comment: I wanted you to describe it in words. If you can do that, you have a chance of translating that into a program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looked like fun, so thought I'd give it a try, and throw in an educational element of introducing you to the wonderful/powerful/flexible world of `numpy`.

I recommend playing with each line to see exactly what's happening, and using that as a learning tool.  Welcome to Python!

How about something like:

```
import numpy as np

m = np.full([7, 7], 'O')
m[0] = 'X'
m[-1] = 'X'
np.fill_diagonal(m, 'X')
for i in m.T:
    print(''.join(i))
```

#### Output:

```
XOOOOOX
XXOOOOX
XOXOOOX
XOOXOOX
XOOOXOX
XOOOOXX
XOOOOOX
```

Basically, it's just creating a 7x7 matrix (`ndarray`) of 'O', then populating the top and bottom rows with 'X', then filling diagonally. The transposing to flip the 'N' the proper way up.

#### The Array:

For completeness, here is what the `ndarray` looks like before the loop and `print`:

```
array([['X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X'],
       ['X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X'],
       ['X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X'],
       ['X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X'],
       ['X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X'],
       ['X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X'],
       ['X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X']], dtype='<U1')
```

Comment: How it will deal if number of rows and columns won't be equal?)

Comment: Good spot. The `fill_diagonal` function will still work, but relies on a square to populate as required in this instance. Just one way to handle the question, as `numpy` is **way** more fun that loops.  :-)